# Hibernate force commit

Tags: hibernate, transactions, commit

I need to force hibernate to commit data, but I don't know how to do because I'm using a transaction manager.

This is my configuration:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

   @RequestMapping("/custom") @ResponseBody @Transaction
public Output customEmi() throws Exception{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=ord.getProg();i<=ord.getProg2();i++){
                   ...
                   /*Here I need a commit!!*/
            }
    }
```

Otherwise the commit is call only after execution exif from the @Transaction method.

Comment: That is the whole point of `@Transactional` either all succeeds or all fails. Also `@Transactional` inside your web-layer wouldn't be something I would encourage, it should be on a service layer).

Comment: I agee with you, however without @Transactional in that method I got *org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session* due to a lazy load on entity.

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` isn't the solution, you should properly create a service layer to process your business needs.

Comment: Ok I will do. Thank you